# How to switch the version of arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I would like to use version 5 of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.

So I installed it via:

```
apt-get install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

But now when I do `gcc --version` it will tell me it's version 7.

How do I tell it to use the older version?

Or do I have to uninstall the newer version completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can run `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5` instead of `gcc`.

[This file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf/filelist) includes the names of the other tools the `gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf` package places in `/usr/bin`, which you may find useful. (You didn't mention what release you're running but I'm guessing it's 18.04, since that release is a popular LTS and it defaults to version 7.)

Note that even if you wanted to use the default version, unless you've changed what `/usr/bin/gcc` points to (which I don't recommend), the `gcc` command is running a GCC compiler that generates *native* executables. This won't be an ARM compiler unless your Ubuntu system is running on ARM. To run the default version of the GCC cross compiler for armhf, use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` (and see [this file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf/filelist)).

Multiple versions of both native and cross compilers can be installed on the same system at the same time. Only the default version of the native GCC compiler is typically invoked with the `gcc` command, however. Other commands have a toolchain prefix, a version suffix, or (in this case) both. This is the case *even* when that non-default compiler is the only compiler installed on the system.

#### If you really must make `gcc` call that compiler...

If you need `gcc` to call that compiler because some other build tool, like `make` is calling `gcc`, the best approach is usually to reconfigure that other tool or to set the `CC` environment variable to the compiler you want. Just making `gcc` run the compiler you need may also not be *sufficient*, because the names of other tools will still run the native versions.

With that said, assuming your your Ubuntu system is *not* an armhf system but you still *really want* `gcc` to run the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5` cross compiler, you have a few options. You could replace the `/usr/bin/gcc` symlink (which on 18.04 links to `gcc-7`), but I recommend against that. Doing that is likely to break anything that assumes `gcc` is a native compiler, and may either interfere with or be undone by future package management operations.

Instead, you could put a `gcc` symlink to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5` in your user's private bin directory `~/bin`. The default per-user `~/.profile`
file adds that directory to `$PATH` when you log in, if the directory exists. Automated builds (like when you run `./configure` or `cmake ..` and then `make`) that you don't customize usually use `cc`, which will continue to be a symlink to a native compiler, so this shouldn't break things.

Personally, I would not want to do even this, because I would *myself* become confused. I prefer that it always be immediately clear what platform my compiler targets, when it is a cross compiler.